# Bayesian Statistics, MCMC methods and "Insensitive" Models

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

Recently, I faced an issue when I am trying to simulate the posterior. For instance, suppose if I have the following data sets $(x_i,y_i)$ and parameters $a,b$.

The model I am fitting is such that:

$ y = k*\frac{1}{x}*\frac{ab}{0.25*(a+b)^2}*\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{(0.25(a+b)^2)}\right)^{-1}$

Here, the function $f(x)$ is complicated, but within the data range, $f(x)$ is approximately constant. Furthermore, I have tried to simulate the data sets $(x_i,y_i)$ from a known value of $a$ and $b$, hoping that it will appear in my posterior.

Suppose that I know $a$ and $b$ are such that $f(x) << 0.25(a+b)^2$. With appropriate priors for $a$ and $b$, I tried to run an MCMC (Adaptive Random Walk Samplers) to simulate the posterior for $a$ and $b$. However, I noticed that the values of $a$ and $b$ are not the values that I have simulated the data from. However, the ratio of $a/b$ is correct.

My explanation to this is that since $f(x) << 0.25(a+b)^2$, then $ y \approx k*\frac{1}{x}*\frac{ab}{0.25*(a+b)^2}$. Hence, from that, we can see that scaling $a$ and $b$ by the same factor will yield the same value of $y$.

Hence, I would like to know if there is a method/any ideas for me to "amplify" the sensitivity of the $\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{(0.25(a+b)^2)}\right)^{-1}$ term so that an approximation is not valid. I am open to any bias introduced by any modification of the model, as long as it is not sufficiently large/significant.

This is because I can simulate the data points, $(x_i,y_i)$, using $a = 1.6, b = 0.4$ and obtain a posterior whereby the median values of $a \approx 5.2, b \approx 1.3$. Thanks in advance!

PS: I have tried to amplify the factor by using $\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{(0.25(a+b)^2)}\right)^{-50}$ instead of a power of $-1$ but it still didn't work out that well.

Comment: I upvoted this because the OP clearly has done work but I do think it is still unclear what is being asked.